# How are arguments passed to anonymous callback functions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning AngularJS and have copied code this basic code from a tutorial (simplified/pseudo code to only include the parts relevant to this question).
The code works for me, but I am trying to better understand how the argument is being passed the the callback in the `success` method.

```js
// jobService object
var jobService = {         
        get : function() {
         return $http.get( 'some/api/url' );
        }
    };

jobService.get().success(function (data) {
        $scope.jobs = data;
    });
```

My question is, knowing that "normally" arguments are specifically passed into the functions when invoked i.e.:

```js
function foo(arg1) {
     alert(arg1); //alerts Hello!
};

foo('hello!');
```

How is the `data` argument being passed into the anonymous callback function?
is it:

- Being "injected" by AngularJS?
- Does the javascript engine simply use variables on the local scope called `data`?
- does the javascript engine look for a `data` property on the parent object if the `success` method?

Comment: The name `data` in the callback function is not compulsory. You could also call it mySuperVariable123 or anything you like (as long as you stick to the naming conventions). The callback function get's invoked when a certain state is entered and is always passed an argument. Thanks to javascript's argument acceptions, you can pass arguments to a function that does not have any parameters or you can pass less arguments than the function has. So the callback function get's called with a certain amount of variables passed and you can choose how many of those you accept with your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the relevant part in the source code:

```
 promise.success = function(fn) {
        promise.then(function(response) {
          fn(response.data, response.status, response.headers, config);
        });

        return promise;
 };
```

Read more on [`GITHUB`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L766).

Comment: great, sometimes the best answer is just a block of code! so the `success` function does the calling, and as @Markai mentioned the name `data` could be changed, and *Thanks to javascript's argument acceptions* , you can choose how many of those arguments to use - thanks

Answer (score 3):

## TL;DR

**We're just defining that anonymous function, not calling it!**

Thus `data` is a function parameter, not a function argument.

---

## Long version

Let's take this into little pieces.

`success()` is a function. It's chain-called after `jobService.get()`. So, whatever the `jobService.get()` call returns, we're calling the success function of that object (say `returnedObject.success()`).

Back to `success()` itself. It can easily read other properties of its object (`returnObject` from the example above). Since we're passing in the anonymous callback function as an argument, `success` can easily do something like (narrowing it down to basic JS):

```
function success(callback) {
    var whatever = "I'm passing this to the callback function";
    callback(whatever);
}
```

which would actually call our anonymous function we passed in, and assign it `whatever` as `data` (**don't forget we're just defining that anonymous function, not calling it!**) . This makes `data` a function parameter, and it is basically a custom name that you use to represent and access what the `success` function passes into its callback function. You can use whatever you want there - this would still work perfectly fine:

```
jobService.get().success(function (somethingElse) {
    $scope.jobs = somethingElse;
});
```

Hope I didn't make this too complicated. I was trying to explain it step-by-step from the plain JS standpoint because you can easily read Angular's source to see what it does, so I thought you needed this simpler explanation.

---

Here's a basic example replicating what's going on there (inspect the JS source, see how the output is the same in all three cases):

```js
var debug = document.getElementById('debug');

function success(callback) {
  var whatever = 'hello world';
  debug.innerHTML += '<br>success function called, setting parameter to <span>' + whatever + '</span><br>';
  callback(whatever);
}

function callbackFunction(someParameter) {
  debug.innerHTML += '<br>callbackFunction called with parameter <span>' + someParameter + '</span><br>';
}

success(callbackFunction);

// anon function
success(function(val) {
  debug.innerHTML += '<br>anonymous callback function called with parameter <span>' + val + '</span><br>';
})

// anon function 2
success(function(anotherVal) {
  debug.innerHTML += '<br>second anonymous callback function called with parameter <span>' + anotherVal + '</span><br>';
})
```

```css
span {
  color: green;
  }
```

```html
<div id="debug"></div>
```

An example using an object, similar to what is done in your original code:

```js
var debug = document.getElementById('debug');

var myObject = {
  whatever: 'hello world',
  success: function(callback) {
    debug.innerHTML += '<br>success function called, fetching object property and setting the parameter to <span>' + this.whatever + '</span><br>';
    callback(this.whatever);
  },
  modifyMe: function() {
    debug.innerHTML += '<br>object property modified<br>';
    this.whatever = 'another world';
    return this; // this is crucial for chaining
  }
}


// anon function callback
myObject.success(function(val) {
  debug.innerHTML += '<br>anonymous callback function called with parameter <span>' + val + '</span><br>';
})

debug.innerHTML += '<br><hr>';

// chaining - calling a success function on a modified object
myObject.modifyMe().success(function(val) {
  debug.innerHTML += '<br>anonymous callback function called with modified parameter <span>' + val + '</span><br>';
})
```

```css
span {
  color: green;
  }
```

```html
<div id="debug"></div>
```

Comment: thanks - your answer helped to reinforce understanding - upvoted :) code examples were helpful - just wondering ,in your `function success(callback) { //... callback.apply(this, [whatever]); }` `this ` is referring to the success function/object ? is that right?

Comment: You're welcome! :) No, no, sorry I confused you, I shouldn't have used `apply()` there, but let me explain: the first parameter of `apply()` is the function context (what `this` would be inside the function) and the second one is the array of parameters (we have one parameter - `[whatever]`). See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply . I'll update my answer in the meanwhile.

Comment: I've added another example now, I tried to replicate your original code in a simpler way.